# XCode client with Java server

Tags: xcode, jakarta-ee

I wonder if I could create an Objective-C client with Xcode and somehow make it communicate with a Java developed application, deployed in a JBoss application server.

Is just that I can't deny that the best visual performance for iPad comes with Xcode, but we already got a bunch of logic in the JBoss app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusing XCode (an IDE) with Objective C (a language). But yes, you can communicate between an IOS app and a Java server in many ways, the easiest probably being via JSON based REST services.

Comment: sorry yes, corrected my question, and thank you for pointing a solution. Do you happen to know of any tutorial, example or framework on the Objective C side related to REST services?

Comment: Take a look at [RestKit](http://restkit.org/). The documentation on the main page is pretty bare but there are some [good tutorials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/) online.